# I have moved files and render does not show the videos anymore how to fix this?

Tags: rendering, video

I was rendering my video and while doing so moved files in my computer. I deleted folders, renamed them, moved them etc. The render had blank parts in it and now when I tried to render again it is completely black and videos don't even show in the preview. It is quite impossible for me to restore all the deleted folders/renamed files on my laptop, is there any other way to recover my work?
I read this is a usual behaviour for Blender when the footage doesn't exist in its original Folder anymore.
Thanks so much!
Ginta

Comment: It's not only the usual behaviour for Blender, this happens with every software. Move or delete the sources and your work is screwed - unless you have a backup.

Comment: There is nothing unusal about this. You can't expect blender (or any other software) to guess where you put the files, or understand what you were thinking when you did such a thing, or to auto-sync-up changes on the OS, or guess the new name of a file. You need to re-link them manually in the source section for the video strips.